Getting this.props.match.params.id is undefined
I have the following react code. I'm trying to access this.props.match.params.id which used to work in previous versions of React, but it's undefined. Can someone please help? Please see the fetch function below
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "../../axios";
import Spinner from "../Spinner/Spinner";

class Event extends Component {
    state = {
        result: null,
        loading: true,
    };

    fetch() {
        console.dir(this.props.match);
        axios
            .get(`/api/events/${this.props.match.params.id}`)
            .then((response) => {
                this.setState({
                    user: response.data.result,
                    loading: false,
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.dir(error);
                this.setState({ error: error });
            });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetch();
    }

    render() {
        if (this.state.loading) {
            return <Spinner />;
        }
        const event = this.state.result;
        return <div className="Event">{event.title}</div>
    }
}

export default Event;

Here's my App.js
export default function App() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
                    <Route path="admin/add-event" element={<AddEvent />} />
                    <Route path="admin/events" element={<AdminEvents />} />
                    <Route path="events" element={<Events />} />
                    <Route path="events/:id" element={<Event />} />
                </Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}


what version of react router are you using?

The newest one @DevonRay

So because newer versions are based around hooks in functional components, you need to add a HOC to your route to access the params:
import { withRouter } from "react-router";


class Event extends Component {

 ... your class component code

}

export default withRouter(Event);


There is a change that may not work with certain versions of react router, in which case you need to create your own HOC:
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";

export const withRouter = (WrappedComponent) => (props) => {
  const params = useParams();
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  return <WrappedComponent {...props} params={params} navigate={navigate} />;
};

